# Subclass of NSDatePicker mouseDown event changes datePicker instance

Tags: swift, instance, mousedown, nsdatepicker

I have instantiated and initialized a subclass of NSDatePicker in AppDelegate -> applicationDidFinishLaunching and overrode mouseDown(with event: NSEvent)in the datePicker subclass. When I press the mouse button in the datePicker and break in its overridden mouseDown func the instance is not the one I instantiated in applicationDidFinishLaunching and so is not initialized.

I've tried creating the instance at different entry points thinking it might be a timing thing but I've gotten nowhere. I'm out of ideas and feeling a little feeble. Any Help?

The datePicker:

```
import Cocoa

class AlarmIVDatePicker: NSDatePicker {
    var viewController: ViewController!

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
    }
    override func acceptsFirstMouse(for event: NSEvent?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        let stop = 0
    }
}
```

The ViewController:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate{

var alarmIVDatePicker: AlarmIVDatePicker!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    alarmIVDatePicker = AlarmIVDatePicker()
    alarmIVDatePicker.viewController = self


}
```

I expected I could access the values I had set but the instance is not the one I created and all the values are nil

Comment: Instantiating a date picker in an AppDelegate is weird.  Why not instantiate it in the `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` of whatever view or window controller that actually uses it?  Also, are you using storyboards or xib files and are you using an `IBOutlet` for that datepicker or how do you reference the date picker in your view?

Comment: Why in the AppDelegate I have no good answer but  agree and so now instantiate it in viewDidLoad:

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        alarmIVDatePicker = AlarmIVDatePicker()
        alarmIVDatePicker.viewController = self
    }

 and referencing it using an IBOutlet:

@IBOutlet  var alarmIVDatePicker: AlarmIVDatePicker!

It isn't the same instance after the mouseDown and its viewController is nil.

Comment: You only need to use an `IBOutlet` if you connected that outlet to your subclassed `AlarmIVDatePicker` living in a storyboard or XIB file.  Are you using either for the view where that picker lives?

Comment: Doesn't matter how I reference the datepicker, with an IBOutlet or declare a class variable. Just thinking I haven't mentioned the datepicker is textual with stepper, don't see what difference that makes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Here's what you can do to track this down.  Add this code to your `AlarmIVDatePicker` class:

```
override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
    Swift.print("AlarmIVDatePicker being called here")
    super.init(frame: frameRect)
}

convenience init() {
    self.init(frame: .zero)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    Swift.print("hey, you DID drop this into a storyboard or XIB file!")
    super.init(coder: coder)
}
```

If you set breakpoints inside these `init` methods, you'll catch when and where they are being called where you did not expect.

Comment: Okay, thanks, so feeling a bit sheepish; the datepicker was added to the view with a storyboard and referenced with an IBOutlet yet I stepped all over that by assigning a new instance to that variable in viewDidLoad. Stepping through the inits you provided set me straight, thanks

Comment: no worries I'm really happy you got it figured out!